# Vagrant command output contains 700+ lines additional info

Tags: vagrant

For each command I enter in Vagrant, I get 700+ additional lines of output.   When I do an up, which has multiple commands, I get nearly 4000 lines.

How do I turn this additional output off?

This occurs with both 1.9.3 and 1.9.4 on Windows 7. My VirtualBox version is  5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2).

I have searched for a few hours with Google and in Stack Overflow, but I cannot find anything that tells me how to turn off all this extra information.   The only thing I could find is that this looks like the output from VBoxManage showvminfo.

```
D:\Vagrant\p1>set vagrant
VAGRANT_HOME=D:\Vagrant\.vagrant.d

D:\Vagrant\p1>find /V "#" Vagrantfile

---------- VAGRANTFILE

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"

end

D:\Vagrant\p1>vagrant status
5.1.22r115126
Name:            p1_default_1494426592172_2291
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Ubuntu (32-bit)
UUID:            65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05
Config file:     D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.vbox
Snapshot folder: D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\Snapshots
Log folder:      D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\Logs
Hardware UUID:   65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05
Memory size:     512MB
Page Fusion:     off
VRAM size:       12MB
CPU exec cap:    100%
HPET:            off
Chipset:         piix3
Firmware:        BIOS
Number of CPUs:  1
PAE:             on
Long Mode:       on
Triple Fault Reset: off
APIC:            on
X2APIC:          off
CPUID Portability Level: 0
CPUID overrides: None
Boot menu mode:  message and menu
Boot Device (1): HardDisk
Boot Device (2): Not Assigned
Boot Device (3): Not Assigned
Boot Device (4): Not Assigned
ACPI:            on
IOAPIC:          off
BIOS APIC mode:  APIC
Time offset:     0ms
RTC:             UTC
Hardw. virt.ext: on
Nested Paging:   on
Large Pages:     off
VT-x VPID:       on
VT-x unr. exec.: on
Paravirt. Provider: Legacy
Effective Paravirt. Provider: None
State:           running (since 2017-05-10T14:29:59.258000000)
Monitor count:   1
3D Acceleration: off
2D Video Acceleration: off
Teleporter Enabled: off
Teleporter Port: 0
Teleporter Address: 
Teleporter Password: 
Tracing Enabled: off
Allow Tracing to Access VM: off
Tracing Configuration: 
Autostart Enabled: off
Autostart Delay: 0
Default Frontend: 
Storage Controller Name (0):            SATAController
Storage Controller Type (0):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      1
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
SATAController (0, 0): D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\box-disk1.vmdk (UUID: d6abf0ee-bf72-41ad-ad05-c037e52c4926)
NIC 1:           MAC: 08002776D8AB, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 2222, guest ip = , guest port = 22
NIC 2:           disabled
NIC 3:           disabled
NIC 4:           disabled
NIC 5:           disabled
NIC 6:           disabled
NIC 7:           disabled
NIC 8:           disabled
Pointing Device: PS/2 Mouse
Keyboard Device: PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:          disabled
UART 2:          disabled
UART 3:          disabled
UART 4:          disabled
LPT 1:           disabled
LPT 2:           disabled
Audio:           disabled
Clipboard Mode:  disabled
Drag and drop Mode: disabled
Session name:    headless
Video mode:      720x400x0 at 0,0 enabled
VRDE:            disabled
USB:             disabled
EHCI:            disabled
XHCI:            disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Available remote USB devices:

<none>

Currently Attached USB Devices:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:  

Name: 'vagrant', Host path: '\\?\D:\Vagrant\p1' (machine mapping), writable

VRDE Connection:    not active
Clients so far:     0

Video capturing:    not active
Capture screens:    0
Capture file:       D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.webm
Capture dimensions: 1024x768
Capture rate:       512 kbps
Capture FPS:        25

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size:      0 MB
OS type:                             Linux26
Additions run level:                 2
Additions version:                   4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129


Guest Facilities:

Facility "VirtualBox Base Driver": active/running (last update: 2017/05/10 14:30:05 UTC)
Facility "VirtualBox System Service": active/running (last update: 2017/05/10 14:30:09 UTC)
Facility "Seamless Mode": not active (last update: 2017/05/10 14:30:05 UTC)
Facility "Graphics Mode": not active (last update: 2017/05/10 14:30:05 UTC)


name="p1_default_1494426592172_2291"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (32-bit)"
UUID="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
CfgFile="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.vbox"
SnapFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="on"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="off"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2017-05-10T14:29:59.258000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\box-disk1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="d6abf0ee-bf72-41ad-ad05-c037e52c4926"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002776D8AB"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"
nic2="none"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\D:\Vagrant\p1"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients=0
vcpenabled="off"
vcpscreens=0
vcpfile="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.webm"
vcpwidth=1024
vcpheight=768
vcprate=512
vcpfps=25
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1494426605576
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1494426609825
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1494426605573
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1494426605573
name="p1_default_1494426592172_2291"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (32-bit)"
UUID="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
CfgFile="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.vbox"
SnapFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="on"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="off"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2017-05-10T14:29:59.258000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\box-disk1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="d6abf0ee-bf72-41ad-ad05-c037e52c4926"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002776D8AB"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"
nic2="none"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\D:\Vagrant\p1"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients=0
vcpenabled="off"
vcpscreens=0
vcpfile="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.webm"
vcpwidth=1024
vcpheight=768
vcprate=512
vcpfps=25
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1494426605576
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1494426609825
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1494426605573
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1494426605573
name="p1_default_1494426592172_2291"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (32-bit)"
UUID="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
CfgFile="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.vbox"
SnapFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="on"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="off"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2017-05-10T14:29:59.258000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\box-disk1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="d6abf0ee-bf72-41ad-ad05-c037e52c4926"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002776D8AB"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"
nic2="none"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\D:\Vagrant\p1"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients=0
vcpenabled="off"
vcpscreens=0
vcpfile="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.webm"
vcpwidth=1024
vcpheight=768
vcprate=512
vcpfps=25
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1494426605576
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1494426609825
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1494426605573
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1494426605573
name="p1_default_1494426592172_2291"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (32-bit)"
UUID="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
CfgFile="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.vbox"
SnapFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="on"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="off"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2017-05-10T14:29:59.258000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\box-disk1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="d6abf0ee-bf72-41ad-ad05-c037e52c4926"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002776D8AB"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"
nic2="none"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\D:\Vagrant\p1"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients=0
vcpenabled="off"
vcpscreens=0
vcpfile="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.webm"
vcpwidth=1024
vcpheight=768
vcprate=512
vcpfps=25
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1494426605576
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1494426609825
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1494426605573
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1494426605573
name="p1_default_1494426592172_2291"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (32-bit)"
UUID="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
CfgFile="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.vbox"
SnapFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="D:\\VMs\\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="65d151c0-ef8e-4ee5-adcd-f1be112a4c05"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="on"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="off"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2017-05-10T14:29:59.258000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\box-disk1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="d6abf0ee-bf72-41ad-ad05-c037e52c4926"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002776D8AB"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"
nic2="none"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\D:\Vagrant\p1"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients=0
vcpenabled="off"
vcpscreens=0
vcpfile="D:\VMs\p1_default_1494426592172_2291\p1_default_1494426592172_2291.webm"
vcpwidth=1024
vcpheight=768
vcprate=512
vcpfps=25
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1494426605576
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1494426609825
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1494426605573
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1494426605573
Current machine states:

default                   running (virtualbox)

The VM is running. To stop this VM, you can run `vagrant halt` to
shut it down forcefully, or you can run `vagrant suspend` to simply
suspend the virtual machine. In either case, to restart it again,
simply run `vagrant up`.

D:\Vagrant\p1>
```

Comment: check all those path https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/#lookup-path to find the global Vagrantfile that is running this command

Comment: Thanks for the response.   The Vagrantfile is in the project directory.   I searched my laptop for all other Vagrantfiles as well.  None of them have the strings "Vbox" or "showvminfo".